# session_start notice in log from function returned by ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

My PHP project relies on information stored in session variables which I set on the first page visit.  I have found that if I don't include session_start in my PHP functions, (edit) which are returned from ajax calls (end edit) the session variables I've set are unavailable. If I do call session start, my error log is littered with notices as follows:
PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /some/file...
I know it is only a notice, and I know I can turn them off but I'd rather not for reasons gleaned from this very forum. Is there a better way of making the session variables available in my functions? I'm I missing something?

(edited to clarify that the notice is generated from php functions which are being return by javascript AJAX calls)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a sessions once every page load in order to use session variables that have been set

**However** you can only start one session per page load. If you're getting errors about sessions already have been started, it's likely because you're trying to start a session more than once. Check your included files and such. A good way to go about this is to have a file that starts your sessions and creates a mysql connection, and then only include that once per page load. Maybe use `require_once` on that file.

Comment: Session_start is included in an include file which is the header for every page. The problem is coming from php functions which are being returned by a javascript AJAX call. If I don't include the session start command in the php functions (returned by ajax), the session variables are not available. The function fails and error log reports: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: value in /some/file

Comment: It's because the errors are pretty explanatory. If you're getting the notice, it's because you're trying to start the session for a second time. Without seeing your code, we can't help you any further than that. There's no other possible thing that the notice could be. If you can't get some variables in your function without starting a session there, then you need to look through your code and find out why. But without more details, there's nothing more that can be done

Comment: please read my comment above about these being in PHP functions returned by ajax calls. Yes, the error is quite explanatory and yet I've been unable to find a solution. I've search SO and tried various methods including an if statement such as if (!$_SESSION){start_session;} as per an old thread on SO

Comment: Yes, but we can't help with you with your ajax problem unless you show us your code. Even if you're calling functions via ajax, you should still be able to include that header file with the session_start, so you shouldn't need to be doing a sessions_start inside the functions themselves

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already called  the `session_start()` function.

This function need to be call only once before you start coding

```
<?php
session_start();

//your logic here

?>
```